# Is there any way to control an rgb strip attached to a 12v rgb header in the motherboard with python?

Tags: python, rgb

My msi motherboard has 2 ports named "JRGB" with 4 pins, one for 12v and the other three for each color. Is there any way to make a python script that can control a rgb strip attached to it ?

Comment: There's probably a way to achieve this. What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the operating system and installed drivers for these jrgb headers. Your Python program needs to talk to these drivers, and I'm pretty confident that there are no platform independent Python libraries available yet. Depending on how the drivers are accessed in your operating system, writing such a library could be relatively simple or quite complicated.

If you're using Windows, you may have luck and MSI has a command line utility that could be executed from Python.